# Where to learn about matrices?

Tags: ruby, matrix

I am programming in Ruby and have wanted to learn about matrices but I can't find any resources for actually learning about them. Are there any good tutorials on matrices and programming? It would be nice if it would be in ruby but other languages are fine too.

Comment: By Matrix, do you mean the linear algebra concept used for transformations?

Comment: I mean whatever http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/classes/Matrix.html is. Sorry, I really have no idea about them, but I want to learn about them and how to use them.

Comment: you're looking for information on "linear algebra".  A google or two and you should find a lot of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not Ruby Specific, but none the less a very good intro do Matrices and linear algebra is [**MIT's OCW 1806 course**](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Mathematics/18-06Spring-2005/CourseHome/index.htm)

Another online resource is the free book [***Linear Algebra* by Jim Hefferon**](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/)

Comment: +1 for that, Strang's videos are what made linear algebra click for me :-) There's also a great free PDF on calculus by him, but I disgress...

Answer (score 0):

If, by matrices you mean the term used in mathematics, take a look at the page from [OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Mathematics/18-06Spring-2005/CourseHome/index.htm)